# How safe is it if I store passwords in app.config in C# .net 4

Tags: c#, .net

I am storing database passwords in app.config as plain text. I am also publishing the application.

How safe is that password stored in app.config? Can I use a disassembler and find it?

Comment: It's about as safe as writing your computer password on a post-it and putting it under your keyboard. I.e. 100% safe until someone flips your keyboard over.

Comment: What can I do so that intruders can't flip the keyboard?

Comment: Make sure the intruders can't GET to the keyboard :)

Comment: @pap - A post-it is the most secure password storage you can get. Even the best hacker won't be able to read it without entrng the room, (unless you point the web cam at it that is)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you cannot find the password with a disassembler. But you can read it plain as day if someone compromises your web server. At the very least, check these links:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203213/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021506-1.aspx
- https://web.archive.org/web/20130501053227/http://aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/advanced/encrypt-conn-str-asp4-cs.aspx
- https://web.archive.org/web/20220722120853/https://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Encrypting-Connection-String.aspx

Better yet, do not use SQL Server Security and instead use Integrated Security and only allow the account your web app (pool) runs under to access the DB.

Comment: TX for the insight

Comment: Since the question was about app.config, not web.config, I suspect this is for a desktop application, and the "hacker" doesn't even need to compromise a web server.

Comment: @JGWeissman nice catch. Though I have heard people refer to "app.config" as the overarching term, I suspect you're correct.

Comment: It is a desktop application.

Comment: @Marin then the plain-text app.config gives your users the keys to the castle. Definitely follow one of the bits of advice, please!